# Wordpress https://example.com not redirecting to https://www.example.com htaccess

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, no-www

I'm using WordPress and moved to `https` recently. I've had some issues since with the domain not redirecting properly.

Currently it works OK but `https://example.com` is not redirecting to `https://www.example.com`.

I have tried a lot of ways but I have not been successful so far.

Here is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[2.1.12]
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on

    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are just missing the `OR` flag:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co\.uk [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
```

Either the bare domain is accessed `OR` you are accessing via HTTP then redirect. The default operator is to `AND` the conditions.

Also, escape the dots in your regex.

Change `R` (temporary) to `R=301` (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK.

**UPDATE:** It's possible that `SERVER_PORT` might not be reporting the correct port (See [UseCanonicalPhysicalPort](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#usecanonicalphysicalport) directive). Alternatively you could use the `HTTPS` variable instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

Another alternative is to test whether the host does *not* start `www`, rather than testing for equality. So, in summary:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. im not sure dont think that works.

Comment: Maybe just a typo, but your question states `example.com`, but your code states `example.co.uk`? Also, clear your browser cache etc. if you have previously been testing with 301 redirects.

Comment: Also, it's possible that `SERVER_PORT` is not set correctly, so `HTTPS` could be used instead. I've updated my answer. (However, this probably won't affect your stated example, `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` since that should be triggered by the very first condition.)

Comment: hi sorry w3d yes you are correct, my website is .co.uk and not .com i did not think it would make a difference, also when i did the first suggestion all my pages redirected to my homepage

Comment: Well, if the domain is supposed to be one thing but you code for another then that is going to make a difference! The "first suggestion" _cannot_ redirect all pages to your homepage - in fact, it is no different to your original code in this respect. If that is happening then there is _something else_ going on. Try clearing browser cache etc.

Comment: thanks, can you help me with the correct setup for .co .uk instead please? thanks

Comment: Just replace `.com` with `.co.uk`. (??)